How to use Pulumi CrossGuard (Policy-As-Code) with .Net
I have a Pulumi Project written in .Net and want to use their Policy-As-Code feature.However the support for Policy-As-Code is planned for future.
Documentation says that Policies can be written in TS/JS/Python and can be applied to stacks written in any language.
How does this work?
How should I proceed?

